# Android applications or their content cut off on Google Pixel 2

Tags: android, screen, crop, screen-orientation, cut

This problem is related to [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480992/androidscanner-library-photo-is-cropped-too-much-on-google-pixel-2). There I have an issue with the specific library.

But a general question for owners Google Pixel 2, Have you some problems with applications where their content or graphics are cut off a little bit?

I don't know whether this library has a problem or maybe software has side effect issue?

Comment: i had the problem, but it was because the user for the pixel 2 had a custom font size. after doing research, i found that doing text size as SP instead of DP caused the issue.

Comment: is there a google bug list for the pixel 2?